# Install the same chrome plug-ins at different places

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

The chrome browser of my computer at workplace has installed some plug-ins. Now I have bought a new laptop. How can I install the same plug-ins at my computer quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sync function from Chrome. It also sync the installed plugins. Read this article: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139